# Bitaddress.org - How does it use random mouse movement?

Tags: private-key, seed, bitaddress.org

I am reviewing https://www.bitaddress.org/. I have downloaded the code from Github. I see first screen they show is to increase randomness on the private key generated.

I am trying to figure it out how it use it in the code. I see the hexcode is shown in a div with id:

```
seedpooldisplay
```

If I look that, I find a method:

```
showPool: function () {
        var poolHex;
        if (SecureRandom.poolCopyOnInit != null) {
            poolHex = Crypto.util.bytesToHex(SecureRandom.poolCopyOnInit);
            document.getElementById("seedpool").innerHTML = poolHex;
            document.getElementById("seedpooldisplay").innerHTML = poolHex;
        }
        else {
            poolHex = Crypto.util.bytesToHex(SecureRandom.pool);
            document.getElementById("seedpool").innerHTML = poolHex;
            document.getElementById("seedpooldisplay").innerHTML = poolHex;
        }
        var percentSeeded = Math.round((ninja.seeder.seedCount / ninja.seeder.seedLimit) * 100) + "%";
        document.getElementById("mousemovelimit").innerHTML = percentSeeded;
        for (var wIndex in ninja.seeder.seederDependentWallets) {
            document.getElementById(ninja.seeder.seederDependentWallets[wIndex]).innerHTML = percentSeeded;
        }
    },
```

Then I loose track where is used, any ideas?. I understand this is used to create the private key,